22.04 do-release-upgrade failed | how to continue
I was doing a release upgrade from 22 to 24 when there was a power failure that cut Internet connection.
As sudo do-release-upgrade -d was hanging I killed the process.
Then I renamed sources.list.distUpgrade to sources.list
but now I can't do do-release-upgrade any more.
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

apt update and apt upgrade to not help.
How can I proceed?
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for ith: 
Hit:1 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                               
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]                                                              
Hit:3 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                             
Get:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security InRelease [7,532 B]
Get:5 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]                  
Get:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-updates InRelease [7,468 B]           
Get:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-security InRelease [7,462 B]                     
Get:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-updates InRelease [7,461 B]                     
Get:9 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [127 kB]
Get:10 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [2,180 kB]
Get:11 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [729 kB]                                                                                 
Get:12 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [103 kB]                                                                         
Get:13 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [2,705 kB]                                                                        
Get:14 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted Translation-en [470 kB]                                                                          
Get:15 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]                                                                    
Get:16 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [356 kB]                                                                     
Get:17 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]                                                                    
Get:18 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,344 B]                                                                      
Get:19 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]                                                                  
Get:20 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [17.8 kB]                                                                  
Get:21 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]                                                                  
Fetched 6,981 kB in 17s (402 kB/s)                                                                                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

the sources.list.d has mixed entries:
.distUpgrade

The 22.04 to 24.04 upgrade door is open, thus the -d option is NOT required; so your use of it could be problematic (it causes https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development to be used where you'll note no mention of the releases you're using there).

If you had an release-upgrade in process; I'd not re-run it in your case; but how I'd proceed would depend on where it was in the process; ie. it downloads all newer packages first which is easy to revert if it was still doing this; then it starts installing packages where you cannot easily revert; and thus you want to continue the process using conventional package commands.  You do mention apt update but running that command is done so you can READ THE OUTPUT, but you've not told us what you saw... What codename was visible is a rather key starting point in my view.

FYI:  I'd expect to use apt full-upgrade rather than apt upgrade, HOWEVER I'd work out the state of where the upgrade aborted before thinking about that  (and that command maybe the 4th command I'd use anyway; or later in the process).. please read prior comment.  (My 2c anyway)

The upgrade was in the process of downloading packages. I reverted source.list so I expect I can rerun do-release-upgrade.

The release-upgrade instructions are found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades which you'll note only mention the -d option "If you want to upgrade early, before upgrades are officially supported, you can pass the -d option when running do-release-upgrade. Do this at your own risk."  That does NOT apply; as the -d now takes a 24.10 system to the development release of 25.04 (plucky) which isn't what you want to do.  Take a look at your sources and you'll see they are not reverted correctly; I see a mixture of jammy and noble which is a problem needing fix

ie.   RE-READ your additional [added] details in your question & you should see a significant problem (referring to my prior comment & esp. bolded codenames)...   jammy being 22.04 and what you'd expect if using 22.04; noble is 24.04 and what you'd expect if using 24.04; you'd not expect to see both unless your system has a problem with its sources.

well, first, if I do -d or not, does not change anything. I get the same message.

the mixed sources.list I realized myself but how to fix that is another question. I could just delete all the noble entries (pun not intended) but these entries might be changed jammy lines.

apt full-upgrade does not change anything.

On a release-upgrade the sources are usually saved in the directory; which allows you to compare with what you had, OR restore them (the release-upgrade tool will do that if you abandon or choose not to proceed and let it do that for you). They're text files so edit them & correct (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) using tools your system has (you didn't specify if desktop, server etc - and we're limited to details you provide, but use whatever you're happy with & already know)

You do NOT want to run, or attempt to run any upgrade or full-upgrade command UNTIL AFTER your sources are correct...  I suggest you re-read my comments, as I attempted to make that very clear; ie. apt upgrade isn't even the 2nd step; its 4th or a later step you'll note I said.. ie. you don't dare attempt to run it until SAFE to run it so as to not break your system)  You had a power outage you said; you need to fix the consequences of that first; then you can start to return to what you were attempting to do.

well, after aborting the release upgrade I did revert the sources.list.distUpgrade to sources.list. Then I ran the commands but it did not work. After searching the web I came here as I did not find my case.

The question remains: how do I fix the sources.list that has mixed entries?

You have many source files; the main source file is /etc/apt/sources.list but don't forget (refer to the repositories link I provided) sources in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ (a directory!) are also used; older releases have this as an empty directory (so anything in there was added post-install) but more recent releases do put sources there.. There are many sources and not just one.

Apart from sources.list.distUpgrade there were many *.distUpgrade files in sources.list.d/
I renamed the *.distUpgrade files, and now it seems to work again. do-release-upgrade continues without error. (I did not do the release upgrade as I had to find a better Internet connection first.)
